# Why would my once tame mouse start biting

Tags: behavior, rodents

I just got a mouse about maybe 2 weeks ago. When I first got him he was a big sweetheart but he would constantly vibrate which worried me. Soon searching on Google why he was I never got a proper answer so that's sorta one thing I want to ask - why would my pet fancy mouse be vibrating?

The second question is why would he randomly decide to bite me. When I first got him I took him out every day and he was super sweet to me. Now today I went and fed him some new food because the other stuff I found out wasn't even mouse food to begin with (long story) I fed him then put my hand down to let him climb on me at first he licked me which freaked me out so I took my hand away. I watched him run around and jump around his cage like he got the zoomies then he would grab food and run into his hide. I put my hand in a second time and began acting as if my hand were another mouse and tapping my fingers on the ground and letting him chase me. He did so for maybe 5 minutes before lunging at me. I got scared again and pulled away. I wasn't really sure if he was lunging at me or if he had just fell on me and he was acting like he wanted attention so I put my hand in again and did the same hand chase thing. And he bit me! Not hard and not enough to cut but he bit me. It scared the crap out of me and I took my hand away. It didn't hurt but I felt so betrayed by him. I've tried asking google but its barely any help at all.

For the record he's about 8 or 9 weeks old and was extremely tamed when he was at his old house. The family even brought out every other mouse they had and let them run around on the ground and play with me. He's a fancy mouse and a boy. He lives alone with no other mice because when I did my research it said male fancy mice should be housed alone.

Hopefully someone can answer these questions and any further questions.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by vibrating?

Comment: I am not an expert in mice, but it sounds as if the mouse is vibrating because it is extremely stressed/scared. Tamed does not mean, that an animal reacts positive to every human it sees. And changing the environment would also need adjustment and to build trust in this new circumstances. Two weeks is not enough to do so. So I would advice to be gentle and patient with the mouse to build up trust :) and stop before the mouse bites, so it sees you respect it's feelings.